# What might cause IDirectDrawSurface::Release blocks and never return?

Tags: directx

DirectDraw 7 is very old APIs but we have a lot legacy code written on that.

Recently I found that directdraw might block on some of it's interface calls, like IDirectDrawSurface::Release, and never never return.  But some times they don't.

I can not find any information by Google so I came here.

Hope you can help me or tell me where I can find help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/d27fd25a5  Call stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A deadlock would imply that you are multi-threading DirectDraw?  This isn't a safe plan.  You should avoid doing it.

Apologies if this isn't the cause.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  When a surface is "locked", any other call to any surface will be blocked until a surface is "unlocked".  That caused a deadlock in my program.